# How do I select projector in UVProject modifer via Python?

Tags: python, modifiers, uv, objects, error

I can access and add the UV Map attribute using this code:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].uv_layer = "projectionunwrap"
```

But when I try to do it with project object it fails:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].projectors.object = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
```

with the error:

> AttributeError: `'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'clear'

When I try different method it says:

> projectors" from "UVProjectModifier" is read-only

[image]

I want to choose `Camera` as a projector.

Answer (score 2):

The `projectors` attribute is a list. You have to access index `0` to make it work:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["UVProject"].projectors[0].object = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
```